# Help. I have reached an issue that is preventing me from installing Brownie

Tags: solidity, blockchain, python, brownie

**I can't for the life of me install Brownie completely through Pipx, Septuptools, or anything. Because my python command doesn't seem to work as normal.**

Preface: So I installed everything that I was told to. Web3, Ganache-Cli, Pipx, everything...

Come to installing Brownie and all hell breaks loose....

First, when I run the command `python3 -m pip install --user pipx`
I get

```
python3 : The term python3 is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the       
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Also with `python3 -m pipx ensurepath`
I get

```
python3 : The term python3 is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the       
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try    
again.
```

However, If I run `python -m pip install --user pipx` it work and I get:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)   
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages) 
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)   
Requirement already satisfied: pipx in c:\users\ahmed\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (0.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: argcomplete<2.0,>=1.9.4 in c:\users\ahmed\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from pipx) (1.12.3)
Requirement already satisfied: userpath>=1.6.0 in c:\users\ahmed\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from pipx) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama>=0.4.4 in c:\users\ahmed\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from pipx) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\users\ahmed\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from pipx) (21.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing<3,>=2.0.2 in c:\users\ahmed\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from packaging>=20.0->pipx) (2.4.7)Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\users\ahmed\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from userpath>=1.6.0->pipx) (8.0.3)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)   
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
```

And If I run `python -m pipx ensurepath` I get:

```
C:\Users\Ahmed\.local\bin is already in PATH.
C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts has been been       
    added to PATH, but you need to open a new terminal or re-login for      
    this PATH change to take effect.

You will need to open a new terminal or re-login for the PATH changes to    
take effect.

Otherwise pipx is ready to go! ✨  ✨
```

Cool.. so then I try running `pipx install eth-brownie` it should work right? No. it doesn't. I get:

```
pipx : The term 'pipx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the       
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try    
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pipx install eth-brownie
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipx:String) [], CommandNot  
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

If I do `python pipx install eth-brownie` I get:

```
C:\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\Ahmed\\Documents\\demos\\brownie_simple_storage\\pipx': [Errno 2] No such file or directory  `
```

If I do: `py -m pipx install eth-brownie` it works initially and I get

```
⡿ installing eth-brownie
```

but then I get the following error right after:

```
Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    C:\Users\Ahmed\.local\pipx\logs\cmd_2021-11-10_14.17.53_pip_errors.log  

pip failed to build package:
    cytoolz

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\functoolz.cp310-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

**Here are the solutions I have attempted so far:**

- I added the Python location to PATH
- I added the Scripts folder location to PATH
- I deleted and re-installed Python **FROM THEIR WEBSITE**
- I deleted and re-installed MS VS Code
- I deleted and re-installed the Python Extension
- I added .local to the Path
- I added PYTHONPATH to System Variables with the addresses of both Python and Scripts folder

***Why isn't my Python command working? Why isn't my PIPX working even though it is clearly installed?***

I do not know what to do anymore. This has been very frustrating and annoying. I have spent about 7 hours so far trying to fix it with no avail.

Comment: Awesome work getting this far! Sometimes the install is really the hardest part! So you likely have python2 installed instead of python3. That's ok, let's run with that. So let's just focus on the `pip failed to build package: cytoolz` error, and you have a few options to fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69679343/pipx-failed-to-build-packages, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/112042/link1120-error-when-attempting-to-install-brownie-with-pipx-install-eth-brownie, https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py/discussions/339